# regular expression to match between [ and ]

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string like

```
[gallery GALLERYNAME] [gallery GALLERYNAME]
```

the GALLERYNAME indicates a name of a gallery

What would a regular expression looks like to match this string?

Comment: What if I would like to do something like wordpress [link class=someClass href=http://urltosomewhere.com ] is that possible with regular expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
    preg_match( "@\[gallery ([^\]]+)\]@", "foo [gallery GALLERYNAME] bar", $match );
    var_dump( $match );
    // $match[ 1 ] should contain "GALLERYNAME"
?>
```

As an alternate:

```
<?php
    preg_match_all( "@\[gallery ([^\]]+)\]@m", "
        foo [gallery GALLERYNAME1] bar
        foo [gallery GALLERYNAME2] bar
        foo [gallery GALLERYNAME3] bar
        ", $match );
    var_dump( $match );
    // $match[ 1 ] should contain an array containing the desired matches
?>
```

Comment: What happens if the string [gallery GALLARY] comes up twice?

Comment: In that case use preg_match_all(). I am not exactly sure what $match will contain in that case; but a var_dump will make things more clear.

Answer (score 4):

```
\[gallery ([^\]]+)\]
```

Comment: The answer is still the same, though.

Answer (score 1):

To match "GALLERYNAME" :

```
^\[gallery\s([A-Z]+)\]$
```